# color picker doesn't show in my code

Tags: jquery, colors, color-picker

I need to use a color picker so I use this:

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about

In my page html I create this:

```
<input id="colore_sfondo_generale" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
```

and my jquery code is:

```
$('body').on('click','#colore_sfondo_generale',function(){
            $('#colore_sfondo_generale').ColorPicker({
                    onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                        $(el).val(hex);
                        $(el).ColorPickerHide();
                    },
                    onBeforeShow: function() {
                        $('#colore_sfondo_generale').ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
                    }
                })
                .bind('keyup', function() {
                    $('#colore_sfondo_generale').ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
                });

        });
```

In my code this is not work and I don't know why. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Did you check the console to see errors?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes but in the console there aren't error

Comment: The answer by Shadow Wizard works. Just be careful with the `jquery.js` provided with the plugin. It's old and doesn't support `.on()` method, instead you'd need to use `.live()`

Comment: @dingo_d no need in either of those actually, just bind it in the `$(document).ready()` which exists since the first version of jQuery. (both `.live()` and `.on()` are meant for elements created on the fly with code, this isn't the case here)

Comment: I tried to test it with the downloaded plugin and when changing `.on` to `.live` it work. But I agree with you, that's entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making things hard for yourself

Would it not be easier to do it like this

http://jsbin.com/lucetuqucu/edit?html,js,output

```js
$('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
 color: '#0000ff',
 onShow: function (colpkr) {
  $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
  return false;
 },
 onHide: function (colpkr) {
  $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
  return false;
 },
 onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
  $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.rachelgallen.com/css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="http://www.rachelgallen.com/css/layout.css" />
    <title>ColorPicker - jQuery plugin</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/js/colorpicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/js/eye.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/js/utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/js/layout.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="colorSelector">
  <div style="background-color:#ff00ff"></div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: (view snippet full page)

Answer (score 1):

This should not come inside a click event handler.

Just attach it directly and it should work as expected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#colore_sfondo_generale').ColorPicker({
        //options here...
    });
});
```

The `.click()` event is handled by the picker itself, and when you attach it in every click, you're disrupting its events.